# Don't understand how accessing CSV file in processing 3 works. Need an explanation

Tags: java, csv, processing

I have created previously a CSV file with textedit called titanicLinearisedDataSet.csv. My goal is to access this file using processing 3 and check whether element in a column are equal to string value "Nil". I don't receive result whereas the csv file contains "Nil"s.

I have joint an image of the CSV file
[(CSV_file_image.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqXfk.png).

Thanks for your help !

```
String [][] array;
void setup() {
    String [] lines = loadStrings("titanicLinearisedDataSet.csv");

    array = new String[lines.length][3];
    int i = 0;

    for(String line: lines){
        String [] pieces = split(line,",");
        if(pieces[3] == "Nil"){
            println("It worked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `==` to compare `String` values. You should use the `equals()` function instead:

```
if(pieces[3].equals("Nil")){
  println("It worked");
}
```

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the `equals()` method, as in `if (a.equals(b))`, instead of `if (a == b)`. A `String` is an `Object`, so comparing them with the `==` operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the `equals()` method will ensure that the actual contents are compared.

Also watch your curly brackets. The code you posted seems to be missing one.

If that doesn't work, try to get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). For example, try printing out the values of `pieces` and `pieces[3]` to see exactly what's going on.